# PostgreSQL: When casting an integer to a non-integer type to force floating point division in PostgreSQL, which number type should I use?

Tags: postgresql, casting, integer, precision, division

I know there are many integer division questions on StackOverflow, but I did not see this one.

Similar to many programming languages, PostgreSQL performs integer division if both operands are integers.

If one has:

```sql
SELECT s.id AS student_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(bc.book_id)) / COUNT(c.id) AS average_books_per_class
FROM student s
     LEFT JOIN class c
        ON c.student_id = s.id
     LEFT JOIN book_class bc
        ON bc.class_id = c.id
GROUP BY s.id
```

Then to get what one intends, one must cast `COUNT(DISTINCT(bc.book_id))` to a non-integer number type. If one does not do so, then Postgres, similar to many programming languages, does integer division which is unlikely to give what one wants as a result.

Postgres supports two syntaxes for doing this cast:

```
CAST( value AS type )
```

for example:

```
CAST( COUNT(DISTINCT(bc.book_id)) AS DOUBLE PRECISION )
```

It also supports the syntax:

```
value::type
```

for example:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(bc.book_id))::decimal
```

Both syntaxes work, personally I prefer the one using `CAST` because it is more explicit (I think explicit is good). Others may prefer `value::type` because it is expressive yet terse -- shorter is often (up to a limit) better.

My question is about the number type to use.

In casting `COUNT(DISTINCT(bc.book_id))` to a non-integer number type, Postgres gives the following types:

- `decimal`
- `numeric`
- `real`
- `double precision`

In my query I chose `DOUBLE PRECISION`.

I am wondering, specifically in the case of division, but also in any other context where one might need to cast an integer number type in PostgreSQL to a non-integer number type, which of the four choices is the best one and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`decimal` and `numeric` are synonyms, so there is one less choice.

This is the proper type if you either need very high precision (use `numeric` without any type modifiers) or if you want to round to a certain number of decimal positions (use `numeric(20,2)` for two decimal positions).

This data type is precise, but slow, because it is a “binary coded decimal” type.

`real` and `double precision` are 4-byte and 8-byte floating point numbers, fast but with rounding errors and limited precision.

Never use `real`, it has very low precision.

In most practical applications it shouldn't matter which of the two remaining types you use for that specific purpose.

Using the `CAST` syntax has the advantage that it complies with the standard.

Remark: `DISTINCT(col)` is syntactically correct, but misleading, because it is not a function. Write `DISTINCT col` instead.